# What is the safest way to subtract two System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME objects

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise-operators, overflowexception, filetime

I wonder what is the safest way to subtract two `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME` objects? I used the following code but sometimes it gives me ArithmaticOverflow exception due to the negative number in Low 32-bit values. I am not sure enclosing the body with `unchecked` will serve the purpose or not. Please give me some suggestion on how to do it safely without getting any runtime exception or CS0675 warning message.

```
private static UInt64 SubtractTimes(FILETIME a, FILETIME b)
        {
            UInt64 aInt = ((UInt64)(a.dwHighDateTime << 32)) | (UInt32)a.dwLowDateTime;
            UInt64 bInt = ((UInt64)(b.dwHighDateTime << 32)) | (UInt32)b.dwLowDateTime;
            return aInt - bInt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *unchecked* to suppress the exception:

```
    public static long FileTime2Long(FILETIME ft) {
        uint low = unchecked((uint)ft.dwLowDateTime);
        return (long)ft.dwHighDateTime << 32 | low;
    }

    static void Test() {
        FILETIME ft = new FILETIME();
        ft.dwHighDateTime = 1;
        ft.dwLowDateTime = -1;
        long value = FileTime2Long(ft);
        Debug.Assert(value == 0x1ffffffff);
    }
```

If desired, you can then convert to DateTime with DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc().

Answer (score 0):

You can convert FILETIME to DateTime object by using [DateTime.FromFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx) method and then you can safely substract DateTime objects.

If you will have a same problem then use method below because [DateTime.FromFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx) doesn't work in all cases thanks to signed/unsigned issues.

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime( System.Runtime.InteropServices.FILETIME ft )
{
  IntPtr buf = IntPtr.Zero;
  try 
  {
    long[] longArray = new long[1];
    int cb = Marshal.SizeOf( ft );
    buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( cb );
    Marshal.StructureToPtr( ft, buf, false );
    Marshal.Copy( buf, longArray, 0, 1 );
    return DateTime.FromFileTime( longArray[0] );
  }
  finally 
  {
    if ( buf != IntPtr.Zero ) Marshal.FreeHGlobal( buf );
  }
}
```